# Entering a word and then searching through and array of words to find the word

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a program which checks to see if words entered (when run) are in an array.  I would like to use a loop for this.

I have created a list of words and tried a for loop however the code  is proving to be erroneous.

```
def Mylist():
    Mylist= [Toyota,BMW,Pontiac,Cadillac,Ford,Opel]
Search=input("Enter a word")
Mylist[1]="Toyota"

    for loop in range (1,6):
    if Mylist[loop]==Search:
    print("found")
    break
```

I have repeated line 4 for the other car manufacturers.

TypeError: 'function' object does not support item assignment

Comment: `MyList` is the name of the function. Not the list.

Comment: Much too complicated, just use `if Search in Mylist: print("found")` - you don’t need a function (and if you write one, use a different name than for the list of words).

Comment: And you probably want quotes around the car-names, unless they're variables as well.

Comment: There are lots of things you need to consider.  1) MyList and Search are not classes so use myList and search instead  2) Your function and list names are the same so it will be confusing; change it to a different name 3) for loop is not indented; fix it too.

Comment: Thank you for the solutions. I have applied these however, when I run the program and enter a word, I get a blank response. Is there a reason as to why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, here some recommendations to start:

- Indentation in Python is IMPORTANT, be careful to have the right indentation. You must take special care when posting code here in SO so your code does not look like complete gibberish.
- You should read [Naming conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#prescriptive-naming-conventions). TL;DR we use [snake_case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) for naming functions and variables.
- If you are not using an IDE (such as [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/)) to program, or something intelligent that shows the information on functions, you should always check out the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/) (it is beautiful).
- Check out the difference between `"Toyota"` and `Toyota`. The first one has quotes, it is a string (i.e. chain of characters), it is a primitive type such as integer and boolean; the second is a token that is to be evaluated, it has to be defined before, such as variables, functions and classes.
- Search in the docs if there is an in-built function that already does the job you want.
- Check out return values in functions. Functions evaluate to None when you do not explicit a return value.

Now to your question. As some people pointed out, there is the `in` keyword that does exactly what you want.

```
CAR_BRANDS= ["Toyota", "BMW", "Pontiac", "Cadillac", "Ford","Opel"]
def check_car():
    word = input("Enter a word: ")
    if word in CAR_BRANDS:
      print("found")
      return True
    print("not found")
    return False
```

> If you don't care about the print you can just do `return word in CAR_BRANDS`

If you actually want to challenge yourself to write the logic, you were right in choosing a for-loop to iterate over the list.

Index in Python starts from 0, and that [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range) does not give you all the indexes to iterate over your list, you are missing the 0 index. Also, we don't like magic numbers, instead of hard-coding the length of your list of car brands, better compute the length!

```
for i in range(len(CAR_BRANDS)):
  if CAR_BRANDS[i] == word:
    print("found")
```

But even better you can directly iterate over the items in your list, no need to do the range, which will give you something like:

```
CAR_BRANDS= ["Toyota", "BMW", "Pontiac", "Cadillac", "Ford","Opel"]
def check_car():
    word = input("Enter a word: ")
    for brand in CAR_BRANDS:
      if brand == word:
        print("found")
        return True
    print("not found")
    return False
```

If you have any more questions, do not hesitate! Happy coding.